# Python saving variables in a json file

Tags: python, json

Im working on a saving system for user names right now. The current variable looks like this: name = input("What is your name"). I have it writing out to a text file.

I tried setting name as a variable without the input, and tried making the input the write function (idk why). No luck with either of those.

```
def welcome():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == "nt" else 'clear')
    print(color.color.DarkGray + "Welcome...")
    sleep(5)
    name = input("Enter Name Here: ")
    name1 = name
    saveUserInp = open("userNames.txt", 'w')
    with open ("userNames.txt") as f:
        f.write(name)
    sleep(5)
    print("Welcome",name1)
    sleep(5)
    menu()
```

Provided above is the code for the welcome function.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 54, in <module>
    welcome()
  File "main.py", line 21, in welcome
    f.write(name)
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

Provided is the actual error given. Line 54 is calling the welcome function, which breaks after I type in my name. Like 21 is the f.write function. I am not sure why it doesn't want to write it into the file.

Comment: You opened userNames.txt for writing, and wrote nothing into it.  You then opened the *same file* for reading (which is the default if you don't specify a mode), and tried to write into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should open the file specifying the open mode if it's different than read:

```
with open ("userNames.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(name)
```

[open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) with no mode provided opens the file in read mode by default, no surprise it's not writable.

By the way, what's the point of opening the file twice? Lines

```
saveUserInp = open("userNames.txt", 'w')
...
saveUserInp.close()
```

might be removed since you open file with the `with` statement.

Comment: Thanks, but I ran into another error. It wont write out into the file.